# Setup rsyslog to send log to remote syslogserver but not to messages/syslog

Tags: elastic-stack, syslog, rsyslog

I am running an ELK-Stack as a central syslogserver and I set up rsyslog to send logfiles, which are not logging into /var/lib/messages by default, to it.

The setup is working very well but since I made the configuration the external logfiles actually show up in the messages file, which is blowing it out of proportion and makes debugging normal systemlogs difficult.

I want the logs to be send to the syslogserver but not into the messages file.

This is my current configuration:

111-elk-syslog.conf:

```
*.* @@IP_OF_THE_SYSLOGSERVER:514
```

101-external-log.conf

```
$ModLoad imfile
$InputFileName PATH_TO_LOGFILE
$InputFileTag FILE_TAG
$InputFileStateFile FILE_TAG
$InputFileFacility local3
$InputRunFileMonitor
```

I know, using filebeat, I could circumvent this but rsyslog is working very well in my enviroment and this application is the only one logging so much, that this is an actual problem.

Comment: When I use some imaginary facility like "elk" for example the logs are not being send to another local log but only to the remote host.
Problem is that, on the syslogserver, the logs are not getting parsed correctly and the whole json content gets dumped into the message field.

Answer (score 0):

I don't understand in detail your setup, but it may help to know that in general in rsyslogd if you don't want further handling of a message that you have matched, you simply repeat the filter on the next line by using `&`, and the action `stop`. For example, you might try

```
*.* @@IP_OF_THE_SYSLOGSERVER:514
& stop
```

Comment: This would prevent all logs from going to the syslog/messages file since it stops the processing right at the include section in the rsyslog.conf.